# Setting a range's function dynamically in VBA

Tags: function, vba, excel

For example, if I have the data

```
  A B C
1|0 0 
2|0 1 
3|1 1
```

And I wanted to set the C column to the sum of A and B I would use the function

```
C1=SUM(A1:B1)
```

etc...
to get

```
  A B C
1|0 0 0
2|0 1 1
3|1 1 2
```

In VBA I could iterate from 0 to 2 and set them individually

```
'iterating on i
Cells(i, 3).FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SUM(R" & i & "C" & 1 & ":R" & i & "C" & 2 & ")"
```

But is there a way to do this without iterating? I just started using VBA, but it seems like there should be an easy way to select a range of cells and set the FormulaR1C1 R or C fields based on the cell being set's row or column.

Comment: have you tried recording a macro while dragging down a formula?

Comment: Agree with @mehow. Record a macro and try watching the code grow as you go through your actions (via the VBE). Also, a tip for you to go forward on: don't use `FormulaR1C1`. Use `Formula` instead.

Comment: I tried recording a macro, but it doesn't do what I need it to do. And how can I replace FormulaR1C1 with Formula? I need numbers to be translated in to column names sometimes also.

Comment: @Nanashi When using R1C1 notation in a formula you must use `.FormulaR1C1` for it to work.

Comment: @D_Bester. That's obvious -- what I'm hinting at is that he doesn't need to use `R1C1`. He doesn't even need to use `AutoFill` (even though that's the safest approach).

Comment: @Nanashi It may be obvious to you and I but best not to assume that a questioner knows that.

Comment: Actually the formula `=SUM(A1:B1)` is relative, not absolute. An absolute reference would be `=SUM($A$1:$B$1)`. But that is not what you want because Excel would not adjust it to each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use R1C1 notation:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
ws.Range("C1:C3").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC1:RC2)"
```

You must use `.FormulaR1C1` for this to work.

SUM(RC1:RC2): R without a number means use the current row (relative reference); C1 means the first column (absolute reference); C2 means the second column (absolute reference). This is called a mixed reference as you have both absolute and relative references in the same address.

Comment: Thanks! This seems like exactly what I was asking. I just need to try it out now.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach doesn't use `AutoFill` and doesn't use `R1C1` notation.

```
Sub HereComesThePain()
    Range("C1:C3").Formula = "=SUM(A1:B1)"
End Sub
```

You can even make it more dynamic to accommodate more rows.

```
Sub HereComesThePainPartTwo()
    'Get the last row in Column A. Same as pressing Ctrl-Up from the last row.
    LRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'Substitute LRow in the respective part.
    Range("C1:C" & LRow).Formula = "=SUM(A1:B1)"
End Sub
```

Let us know if this helps.

EDIT:

In the interest of proof, here's a screenshot:

[image]

The reason for this is very similar to the nature of `AutoFill`: Excel immediately adjusts the formula for you to fit the given range.

Comment: Wouldn't that set the formula to the static sum of A1:B1, instead of that row's A and B? So Formula = "SUM(A" & LRow &"B" & LRow &":)"? Again, I'm not sure how to use this if Formula instead of FormulaR1C1 if the column is the one that is changing. I feel like that is why FormulaR1C1 exists.

Comment: It works because Excel assumes you want to use a relative reference and it does an automatic autofill without you needing to do it explicitly.

Comment: Ah, that's good to know. I wouldn't have guessed that excel makes that assumption (I don't use Excel or VBA much). This is cleaner than the autofill code. Thanks.